# Hide the browser address bar in Android

Tags: android, xml, jakarta-ee

I've created a WebView app and everything works fine.
I'm new to Android.The only remaining feature I need for the app is to hide the address bar. Because I want the app to look more like a regular app and not a webpage within a web browser window.

My code is like this,

```
package com.Mobi.ebookread;

public class Mobile extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.helloWebView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

i think there is a problem. webview does not have an address bar, seems that the browser app is getting opened. It could be possible that there is a redirection happening and that causes the browser app to open up, and you did not intercept that redirect using a WebViewClient and shouldOverrideURLLoading()

Below is how the webview looks like.

[image: WebView]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I Try with this. Its worked for me..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    //webview use to call own site
    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //use to hide the address bar      
    webview .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); //to store history    
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); 
    }
```

and your entire main.xml(res/layout) look should like this:

```
`<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>`
```

don't go to add layouts.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.helloWebView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
   }
});
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```